# Is it faster to .makeCopy() or create a new doc and append elements in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use Google Apps Script to make copies of documents. We have a large number of users and for the sake of concurrency, we would like to limit access to the same file call for the template. In the end, is it faster to var newDoc = file.makeCopy() and copy the file and use a lock or create a new doc from scratch and append elements to it in GAS?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind...I ran some tests with .makeCopy(); vs. creating a new doc and copying doc elements into it...

Copying the elements wins hands down. As a bonus, because of it's speed, it doesn't lead to many file conflicts with simultaneous and concurrent calls.